# App Store Connect is rejecting an app release saying "Missing Purpose String in Info.plist" but the app does not need those permissions

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store-connect

I have just done an iOS App Store bundle upload and had it rejected for the following reasons :

> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
> Info.plist file should contain a NSContactsUsageDescription key with a
> user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your
> app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the
> App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose
> string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference
> APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these
> APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the
> developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of
> their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
> Info.plist file should contain a NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with
> a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why
> your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to
> the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose
> string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference
> APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these
> APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the
> developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of
> their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
> Info.plist file should contain a NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key with
> a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why
> your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to
> the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose
> string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference
> APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these
> APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the
> developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of
> their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
> Info.plist file should contain a NSMotionUsageDescription key with a
> user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your
> app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the
> App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose
> string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference
> APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these
> APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the
> developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of
> their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
> Info.plist file should contain a NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription
> key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and
> completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps
> submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to
> include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs,
> they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app
> might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can
> contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a
> version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).

This is a Flutter app.

The permissions it wants descriptions for are `NSContactsUsageDescription`, `NSCalendarsUsageDescription`, `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription`, `NSMotionUsageDescription`, `NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription`.
But our app doesn't use contacts, the calendar, apple music, motion detection, nor speech recognition.

I know how to fix these to get the submission to work, but I don't understand why Apple thinks our apps need these permission.

### Why does App Store Connect think the app needs these permissions?

#### Is there any way to see what permissions it thinks the app needs, and/or why?

---

**Info.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>my_app</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
        <string>LaunchScreen</string>
        <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
        <string>Main</string>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>
        <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app needs access to location when open and in the background.</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: NB: our app uses the following packages :
  crypto: 2.1.4
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  sqflite: ^1.3.0
  path_provider: ^1.6.7
  json_schema: ^2.2.1
  flutter_map: ^0.8.2
  user_location: ^0.1.2
  permission_handler: ^5.0.0+hotfix.4
  xml: 3.6.1
  poly: ^1.0.7+2
  audioplayers: ^0.15.0
  flutter_slidable: ^0.5.4
  carousel_slider: ^2.1.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

Comment: Can you add the content of your `info.plist` file? Looks like it is missing some needed `string` tag for the respective `key` tag.

Comment: @Timilehin Jegede you are right. You can add vaule for it. The info.plist file is found in the IOS module (ios/Runner/info.plist) or you can open xcode and search Info.plist add some "Privacy - ..." you missing.

Comment: @TimilehinJegede You are correct, that's what's needed to fix the submission, but that is not what I'm asking about --- I want to know why it is that App Store Connect believes my app needs these permissions.

Comment: @TimilehinJegede I've added my info.plist to the question now.  I don't see anything in it which suggests the app needs those permissions

Answer (score 8):

The issue is coming from  `permission_handler` plugin. It contains code for handling all the permissions that needed for an app.
Follow their [setup process](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#setup) on iOS section, they have explained how to remove permissions that you do not use on your application.

[image]

#### Update (2021-April)

---

There is known [issue](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/432) that, following their setup procedure won't work with latest version of `permission_handler` and Flutter 2. You have to manually add all permissions to your `info.plist` file.

Comment: In my case, I had given all the permission values as 0 (like 'PERMISSION_EVENTS=0'), all other errors were removed. But the Calendar event was still showing as an error. So I had to specify the NSCalendarsUsageDescription in my info.plist file even though I'm not using Calendars in my application to remove this error. Hope this helps someone. It is very strange that the permission_handler plugin has such an issue. Hopefully, they fix it in any of the upcoming version